# "multipart/form-data" with a List in Asp Net Core 3.1 returns Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, model-binding

I'm trying to send to a Controller a "multipart/form-data" with complex data, including a List. All values, including the File, are correctly binded, but when I add the List, it returns BadRequest. It is not binding the content to the list, but instead returns a string.

The only solution so far was to receive the list as a string and then parse it to a List.

Someone knows why it isn't binding the List?

Thanks.

**Bad Request Response**

```
"errors":{"Categories":["The value '[2,3]' is not valid."]}
```

**Model**

```
public class CreateAssetCommand
{
   public string FileURI { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
   public List<int> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizePolicy(UserPolicies.ManagerRights)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Insert([FromForm] CreateAssetCommand command)
{
...
```

**HttpRequestMessage Content**

```
------MyBoundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=FileURI

"key.fbx"
------MyBoundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Name

"1967753d-c577-4c50-958c-10af029b4032"
------MyBoundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Image

null
------MyBoundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Categories

[2,3]
------MyBoundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Image; filename=helmet.png; filename*=utf-8''helmet.png

�PNG
```

**Command Object**

```
_createAssetKeyValid = new CreateAssetCommand { 
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), FileURI = "key.fbx" , 
                Categories = new List<int> { 2,3 }
            };
```

**Object to Dictionary**

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> ObjectAttributesToDicionary(object obj)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> stringContents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                stringContents.Add(prop.Name, JsonSerializer.Serialize(prop.GetValue(obj)));
            }

            return stringContents;
        }
```

**multipart/form-data HttpRequestMessage Builder**

```
public static HttpRequestMessage PrepareMultipartFormWithFile(
            HttpMethod method, string url, Dictionary<string, string> stringContents, string filePath = null)
        {
            MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("----MyBoundary");

            foreach (var content in stringContents)
            {
                multiPartContent.Add(CreateJsonContent(content.Value), content.Key);
            }

            if (filePath != null)
            {
                ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent;
                CreateFileContent(filePath, out string fileName, out byteArrayContent);

                multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "Image", fileName);
            }

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
            request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
            request.Content = multiPartContent;

            return request;
        }
```

**Temp Solution**
So far, a temporary solution is to create a Custom Binder

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(value);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the client side codes that send the data? For how to bind collection data, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections

Comment: Hi @mj1313
I added to the question the test method that builds the Request Message and the method that decomposes the CreateAssetCommand into its properties, so I can send it ass a multipartform. 
For the presented error, it uses a CreateAssetCommand that is converted to a Dictionary with the properties and values, and then it creates the requestMessage.
In the text, it presents some formats for the binding using collections. So, for a List, I can’t just JsonSerialize, like other objects?